# Результат a += a++

Tags: java, autoincrement

Почему после выполнения такого кода

```
int a = 0;
a += a++;
```

В `a` записывается `0`, а не `1`?

Comment: Не эквивалент. `=` и `+=` достаточно существенно отличаются в поведении, чтобы рассматривать поведение этих примеров отдельно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Выражение

```
a += a++;
```

по определению оператора `+=` эквивалентно выражению

```
a = a + a++;
```

В языке Java вычисление таких выражений и моменты возникновения побочных эффектов операторов однозначно упорядочены. Операнды бинарных операторов вычисляются слева-направо:

1. Левая часть оператора присваивания тривиальна.
2. Вычисляется правая часть оператора присваивания: выражение `a + a++`.
3. Для этого сначала вычисляется левый операнд этого подвыражения: `a`. Значение `a` в этот момент равно `0`. Значит значение левого операнда равно `0`.
4. Затем вычисляется правый операнд этого подвыражения: `a++`. Значение `a` в этот момент равно `0` и при вычислении `a++` значение `a` увеличивается на 1. Однако результатом постфиксного инкремента по определению является *исходное* значение `a`, то есть `0`.
5. Теперь вычисляется бинарный `+`, то есть все подвыражение `a + a++`. Оно дает результат `0` (`0 + 0`). Обратите внимание, что в этот момент переменная `a` уже имеет значение 1, полученное на шаге 4.
6. Затем выполняется присваивание: в переменную `a` заносится результат вычисления правой части, то есть `0`. Это и есть финальное значение `a`.

Таким образом формально переменная `a` в течение какого-то мгновения "успела" получить значение `1` на шаге 4, но потом её значение было снова возвращено в `0` оператором присваивания на шаге 6

Обратите внимание, что если выражение `a = a + a++` в конечном итоге заносит `0` в `a`, выражение `a = a++ + a` занесет в `a` значение `1`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Читаем спецификацию: [jls-15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

   > The value of the postfix increment expression is the **value** of the
   >   variable **before** the new value is stored.
2. Читаем про [приоритеты](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

**Итог:** сначала вычисляется `a++` в самом `a` теперь `1`, но результатом самой операции инкремента будет оригинальной значение `a`, т.е. `0`; в итоге выражение сводится к `a += 0;` и в `a` будет `0`.

Comment: Информация по ссылке на "приоритеты" упрощена до такой степени, что является грубо некорректной. "Operators with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with relatively lower precedence."? Нет, ни в коем случае! Несмотря на то, что `++` обладает более высоким приоритетом, чем `+=`, левая часть `+=` в данном примере будет вычислена раньше `++`. Ссылка на jls-15.14.2 содержит корректную инофрмацию.

Comment: @AnT хм, я просто думал, что очевидно, что `+= ++` трансформируется в `=  + ++`, поэтому не стал про это писать.